# Why nesting these observables is not working in Ionic-Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm experimenting with Observables but I still couldn't figure out why this is not working.
All the methods seems to be working fine if I call them outside the pipe **but** when I nest them this way it simply won't work:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password): Observable<Session> {
    return from(this.firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password))
        .pipe(map(v => v.user as unknown as User),
            switchMap(this.userDatabase.createUser),
            map(this.userDatabase.createSession)
        );
}
```

### it throws this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
>
> ```
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.create (database-core.service.ts:57)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.createUser [as project] (database-user.service.ts:28)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:30)
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
> at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
> at subscribeToPromise.js:5
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
> at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27437)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
> ```

### database-user:

```
createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return super.create(this.DB_URL, user) //<--- line 28
        .pipe(map(v => v as unknown as User));
}

createSession(user: User): Session {
    const newSession: Session = {
        firstLogin: false,
        id: user.id
    };
    this.angularFirestore.collection('session').doc(user.uid).set(newSession)
        .catch(e => {
            throw new Error(e);
        });
    return newSession;
}
```

### In database-core:

```
constructor(
    private globalService: GlobalService,
    protected httpClient: HttpClient
) {}
// (...)
protected create(url: string, data: any): Observable<JsonObject> {
    return this.httpClient.post<JsonObject>(url, data, this.globalService.getHttpOptions()) //<-- lines 57
        .pipe(catchError(DatabaseCoreService.handleError)); 
}
```

### Subscribing to the observable:

```
createUser(email, password) {
    this.authService.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).subscribe();
}
```

### App-Module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    // (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

I believe the problem is occurring in your `super` class where `http` seems to be `undefined`.

See below [Error reproduction on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a3u12d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the above I have two classes

**MySuperClass**

```typescript
export class MyClass {
  constructor(private htttp: HttpClient) {

  }
  create = user => this.htttp.post('some URL', user)

}
```

**MyComponentClass**

```typescript
export class AppComponent extends MyClass implements OnInit {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.create({ name: "User" }).subscribe({
      next: console.log
    });
  }
}
```

In the above the error is thrown. This should be the error you are facing

### Solution

To solve this, you can set the value of `http` in the `constructor` of the `super` class

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vsa8jf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In this I have passed the `http` property to the `super` class and set it

**MySuperClass**

```typescript
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export class MyClass {
  http: HttpClient;
  constructor(_htttp) {
    this.http = _htttp;
  }
  create = user => this.http.post("some URL", user);
}
```

**MyComponentClass**

```typescript
export class AppComponent extends MyClass implements OnInit {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.create({ name: "User" }).subscribe({
      next: console.log
    });
  }
}
```

The above solves, the problem. Check if this is the problem in your code